Flutter pre-initialize video
In some apps like Facebook(watch, Feed), Tiktok video are played immediately without delay (even in facebook web application) how to achieve that in Flutter.
I have tried HLS video and still there are delay.
I have tried MediaKit and still there are delay.
What I am trying to do is cache this function
      VideoPlayer(VideoPlayerController.networkUrl(Uri.parse("url")).initialize();

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
